# HTML5 input type range to update element attribute

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

What I'm trying to do, is have a `<input type="range">` update an elements attribute:
https://jsfiddle.net/kjunyxrj/

When the user slides the slider, the `data-layout` of the element should change.
This works fine in Edge, Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11.

Comment: In your fiddle I can see `$(layouttarget).attr`. Are you using jquery?

Comment: I fixed it by using jQuerys `change` instead:
https://jsfiddle.net/kjunyxrj/4/